# C# Exception thrown for when class isn't fully initialized

Tags: c#

What exception should I raise to tell the caller that the class isn't fully initialized? The only exception I found was TypeInitializationException, but that didn't seem appropriate.

Comment: I would generally expect that you could design your program in such a way that it's impossible for the type to ever be used before it is initialized, rather than throwing an exception if the caller isn't capable of managing it all on their own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's impossible for a class to not be fully initialized upon use, unless you're doing some manual `Init()` type method call. If you're using constructors and initializer syntax, it's guaranteed by the c# lang spec to be initialized. If you need to throw something, I usually use `InvalidOperationException` with a note saying "call Init first!"

Comment: +1 From the documentation InvalidOperationException: The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state.

Answer (score 2):

create your own `ClassNotFullyInitialized` exception.

```
public class ClassNotFullyInitializedException : Exception{
   ...
}
```